# How to add lines at the beginning of either empty or not file?

Tags: bash, sed

I want to add lines at beginning of file, it works with:

```
sed -i '1s/^/#INFO\tFORMAT\tunknown\n/' file
sed -i '1s/^/##phasing=none\n/' file
```

However it doesn't work when my file is empty. I found these commands:

```
echo > file && sed '1s/^/#INFO\tFORMAT\tunknown\n/' -i file

echo > file && sed '1s/^/##phasing=none\n/' -i file
```

but the last one erase the first one (and also if file isn't empty)

I would like to know how to add lines at the beginning of file either if the file is empty or not

I tried a loop with `if [ -s file ]` but without success

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `i` command in `sed`:

```sh
file='inputFile'
# insert a line break if file is empty
[[ ! -s $file ]] && echo > "$file"

sed -i.bak $'1i\
#INFO\tFORMAT\tunknown
' "$file"
```

---

Or you can ditch `sed` and do it in the shell using `printf`:

```sh
{ printf '#INFO\tFORMAT\tunknown\n'; cat file; } > file.new &&
mv file.new file
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but it doesn't work when file is empty

Comment: yes I realized that. Just made an edit, please check

Comment: Perhaps `{ echo -e 'a\nb\nc'; cat file; } | sponge file` where sponge is from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the insert command (`i`).

```
if [ -s file ]; then
    sed -i '1i\
#INFO\tFORMAT\tunknown\
##phasing=none' file

else
    printf '#INFO\tFORMAT\tunknown\n##phasing=none' > file
fi
```

Note that `\t` for tab is not POSIX, and does not work on all sed implementations (eg BSD/Apple, `-i` works differently there too). You can use a raw tab instead, or a variable: `tab=$(printf '\t')`.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitely creating a new file, then moving it:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo -e '#INFO\tFORMAT\tunknown' | cat - file > file.new
mv file.new file
```

or slurping the whole content of the file into memory:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
printf '#INFO\tFORMAT\tunknown\n%s' "$(<file)" > file
```

Answer (score 1):

With plain bash and shell utilities:

```
#!/bin/bash

header=(
        $'#INFO\tFORMAT\tunknown'
        $'##phasing=none'
)

mv file file.bak &&
{ printf '%s\n' "${header[@]}"; cat file.bak; } > file &&
rm file.bak
```

Answer (score 0):

It is trivial with `ed` if available/acceptable.

```
printf '%s\n' '0a' $'#INFO\tFORMAT\tunknown' $'##phasing=none' . ,p w | ed -s file
```

---

- It even creates the file if it does not exists.